# Counting chords intersections in a circle

Tags: algorithms, graphs, combinatorics, balanced-search-trees

The problem is:

Given 2n distinct endpoints of n chords on the unit circle, count the number of intersections between chords (if k chords intersect at one point,
that point counts as $\binom{n}{2}$ intersections). What is the complexity of this problem as a function of n?

The solution algorithm is given in this [paper](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs/BLRVW84.pdf). $S$ is like an order statistic tree right? I don't understand why the author put $S\leftarrow S - \{E_{j}\}$ outside $else$. Why you would want to remove $\{E_{j}\}$ at the end of every loop?

$i\leftarrow 1 \\
intersections \leftarrow 0\\
S\leftarrow \phi\\
while(i\leqslant2n)\left \{\\
\qquad j \leftarrow   \sigma _{i} \\
\qquad if(seen_{j}=FALSE)\left \{/*open\ an\ interval\ for\ j*/\\
\qquad\qquad seen_{j}\leftarrow TRUE\\
\qquad\qquad E_{j}\leftarrow i\\
\qquad\qquad S\leftarrow S\ \cup\ \{i\}\\
\qquad\right \}else\left\{/*close\ the\ interval\ for\ j\ and\ count\ intersections*/\\
\qquad\qquad intersections\leftarrow intersections \ +\ |\{x|x\in S\ \wedge x>E_{j}\}|\\
\qquad\right\}\\
\qquad i \leftarrow i+1\\
\qquad S\leftarrow S-\{E_{j}\}\\
  \right \}
$

Comment: Have you tried running the algorithm by hand step by step for some small examples such as when $n=2$ or $n=3$ or $n=4$? If not, please do it now. If yes, can you tell us what you have found regarding "Why you would want to remove {Ej} at the end of every loop?"

Comment: The phrase "the complexity of this problem" does not make sense to me. If you meant the complexity of the algorithm in that paper, it is $O(n\log n)$ as shown in the paper.

Comment: @Apass.Jack First of all, the problem was quoted from that paper without modification. Not what I meant, it’s what the author proposed in the paper. I think it’s clear enough that the author is talking about the complexity of the algorithm. Second, I don’t care the complexity cause it’s quite obvious. My doubt is about the correctness of the algorithm. In my opinion, I think $S \leftarrow S - E_{j}$ should be in the else block. I want to double check if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is some printing mistake it seems, the expression S←S−{Ej} must be inside `else` block otherwise `S` will always be empty.Since we are adding the elements in `if` block and removing it at last making no sense. The correct pseudo code looks like below:

$i\leftarrow 1 \\
intersections \leftarrow 0\\
S\leftarrow \phi\\
while(i\leqslant2n)\left \{\\
\qquad j \leftarrow   \sigma _{i} \\
\qquad if(seen_{j}=FALSE)\left \{/*open\ an\ interval\ for\ j*/\\
\qquad\qquad seen_{j}\leftarrow TRUE\\
\qquad\qquad E_{j}\leftarrow i\\
\qquad\qquad S\leftarrow S\ \cup\ \{i\}\\
\qquad\right \}else\left\{/*close\ the\ interval\ for\ j\ and\ count\ intersections*/\\
\qquad\qquad intersections\leftarrow intersections \ +\ |\{x|x\in S\ \wedge x>E_{j}\}|\\
\qquad\qquad S\leftarrow S-\{E_{j}\}\\
\qquad\right\}\\
\qquad i \leftarrow i+1\\
\\
  \right \}
$